# AnyLogic: Execute Java Function which is embededded in the Main agent from a Java Class

Tags: anylogic

I want to execute a java function in a java class. The function is embedded in the Main agent and I want to call this function from a java class.
How can I do that? Do I have to instantiate a main agent? Or do I have to declare my java class as a subclass of Main?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

one way is to add main as a variable of your class, so you can add it in the constructor of your class so then you can just do `main.yourFunction();` anywhere in your class.

```
public class YourClass{
   public Main main;
   public YourClass(Main main){
       this.main=main;
   }
}
```

so when you instantiate your class you do `new YourClass(main);`

Comment: True. In some cases, you can also flag your function as `static` and call it from your Java class with `Main.myFunction()`. But you need to know what "static" means and when to use it this way. 90%, Felipe's way is the best